# Python Windows cmd command format

Tags: python

So I'm trying to make a simple python script to create a user in Windows but I'm having issues getting Python to format the command in cmd. Let's say the user is test and the password is 12345 the output with the code I have below would be net usertest12345 /add instead of net user test 12345 /add. Any help would be appreciated!

```
import getpass, os
user = input("Please enter a username: ")
password =  getpass.getpass()
add = ' net user'
add2 = ' /add'
add3 = add +  user + password + add2
os.popen(add3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add some spaces in between?

```
add3 = add + ' ' + user + ' ' + password + add2

print(add3)  # --> net user test 12345 /add
```

Comment: Thank you very much, my friend! I've been staring at code for too long haha. I will accept your answer when the set time limit is up!

Answer (score 1):

Or even better, use python string formatting:

```
import getpass, os

user = input("Please enter a username: ")
password = getpass.getpass()
addUser = "net user {user} {pw} /add".format(user=user, pw=password)
print(addUser)
```

Resulting in the following output:

```
Please enter a username: test
Warning: Password input may be echoed.
Password: 12345
net user test 12345 /add
```

That being said, you probably also want to handle exceptions ...

Comment: Thank you my friend that is actually a very useful method!